# Reading bin file as int16

Tags: c, binary, int, hex

After reading a binary file into my program, I have a `D6` which is `HEX`. 
The problem is I get `214` instead of `-42` from the interpretation `D6`. After lots of research on the internet, I understood that I need to use `int16` to get `-42`. 
Can someone please tell me how I can do this in C?

It's a very long file of code, I tried as minimum as possible to post my code here:

```
uint32_t prog_size;
byte_t *text_buffer;
int program_counter = 0;
fread(&prog_size,sizeof(uint32_t),1,fp); // you can assume the first 4 bytes 
                                         //of the binary code indicates the 
                                         //size of the program
prog_size = swap_uint32(prog_size); // for little-endianness
text_buffer = malloc(sizeof(byte_t)*prog_size);
fread(text_buffer,sizeof(byte_t),prog_size,fp);

void match(int program_counter)
{
    switch (text_buffer[program_counter])
    {
      case OP_BIPUSH:
        program_counter++;
        push(text_buffer[program_counter]);
        break;
    }
}
printf printf("%u\n", text_buffer[program_counter] );
// assume that text_buffer[program_counter] is D6 in HEX
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please create [mcve] of your current implementation.

Comment: I hope it's clear by now, thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I solved it.

in the function `Push` I should've used `int8_t` instead of `int32_t`